# Sublime Text 3 with RubyTest + Spork

Tags: rspec, sublimetext3, spork

I've run into a curious output issue. When running my RSpec tests under ST3, I have normal output to the test window without any issue. When I fire up Spork in one particular project, my test output appears in the spork terminal window, but not in the ST3 test pane. The only test output that appears in the ST3 pane is the Finished notice: "[Finished in 3.1s]"

This is the only project where this happens, and I have other projects that output tests with the standard behavior.

I know there are a lot of moving parts here, between ST3, Spork, RubyTest, and RSpec, but I'm curious if anyone else has seen anything similar.

Thanks

Spork window notice:

```
Running tests with args ["--color", "--format", "Fuubar",        "spec/lib/search/client_index/client_evaluations_interactor_spec.rb"]...
Run options: exclude {:sql_lite=>true}
Run options: exclude {:sql_lite=>true}
.  6/6:         100% |==========================================| ETA:  00:00:00
  6/6:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:02
```

Spork window deprecation notice:
Deprecation Warnings:
Instantiating a `RSpec::Core::CommandLine` with an array of options is deprecated. Use Instantiate a `RSpec::Core::Runner` with a `RSpec::Core::ConfigurationOptions` instance instead. Called from local_user.../gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `new'.

If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 2.25 seconds
6 examples, 0 failures

Finished in 2.25 seconds
6 examples, 0 failures
Done.